# filteredArrayUsingPredicate raises EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iphone5 not on iphone6

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, iphone-5, iphone-6

I have this:

```
// self.theWholeEventsArray is NSMutableArray * populated properly after segue

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd@hh:mm"];

NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015/05/29@00:00"];
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015/06/03@00:00"];

NSPredicate *tmpPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K => %@) AND (%K =< %@)", @"dateOfTheEvent", startDate, @"dateOfTheEvent", endDate];

NSArray *selectedDateArray = [self.theWholeEventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:tmpPred];
```

It works perfectly on iphone6 and iPad, but crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 on iphone5 and iphone4s. I see the issue on simulator and device too.
Anyone can explain me why and how to solve this crash?

Comment: Hello it is working fine in iPhone5 simulator. Can you please paste here the complete error.

Comment: I added NSZombieEnabled support and I get this error: 2015-05-06 12:49:10.542 tjf[9012:193121] *** -[__NSDate compare:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x786e96c0. I cannot understand which object 0x786e96c0 is. Obviously, it changes everytime...

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be happening on some devices and not others, unless iOS is firing memory warnings on lower devices with less mem. The crash message is clear: it seems that somewhere in your array, `NSDate` objects are being released before they should be. I'm assuming you have a load of custom `Event` objects that have a date property? If so, how many are you keeping in memory at any one time?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions and see what a stack trace looks like at the time of the crash.

Comment: @RASS, thank you too. It was very surprising to me to see that dateOfTheEvent property was (nonatomic, **assign**), not strong!!! I figured it out using a for cycle instead of filteredArrayUsingPredicate, discovering that dateOfTheEvent was a zombie... Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

My Event class had the `dateOfTheEvent` property declared as `(nonatomic, **assign**)`, so that wasn't kept in the destination view controller after segue.